# how to use the CSS trick :not() in styled component react

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, styled-components

[Container with the icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEK9W.png)

i want  to display none everything in the container except the Avatar.
code and picture as support

Thanks[Code of the Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfLee.png)

```
 <RightContainer>
    <IconButton>
      <NotificationsIcon style={{ color: "#b1bdb4" }} />
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton>
      <img src="/images/work.svg" alt="" />
    </IconButton>
    <AvatarProfile src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/ADGmqu92jhn39aYEn_N3jFj7cmQkvGBDfgbz53Lmv_8z3Q=s32-c-mo" />
  </RightContainer>

const RightContainer = styled.div`


flex: 0.15;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;

  @media (max-width: 520px) {
    display: none;
  }
```

`;

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please post your code as text instead of a picture?

Comment: Hey mate, can you share the relevant code in your question? It would be helpful to see the elements present in RightContainer

Comment: I never used styled component, so I'm not sure if this is correct, but based on their docs, you can try to use nesting and referring to other components. Something like that: " & > *:not(${AvatarProfile}) { display: none }"

Comment: Thanks Zion Ay, it's working!  really Appreciate